# Spectral radius Volterra operator with an arbitrary kernel from $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

How to prove that the spectral radius $r \left( V_K \right)$ of a Volterra operator with an arbitrary kernel is zero.

$$V_K : L^2 \left[a,b \right] \rightarrow L^2 \left[a,b \right]$$
$$ (V_Kf)(x) = \int_a^x K \left(x,y \right) f(y) dy, $$
where $K\left(x,y \right) \in L^2 \left( \left[ a,b \right] \times \left[ a,b \right] \right)$

I know how to prove this if the kernel is bounded, but how to act in an arbitrary case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
   |V_K^nf|^2= \\
= \left|\int_{a}^{x}K(x,x_{n-1})\cdots\int_{a}^{x_2}K(x_2,x_1)\int_{a}^{x_1}K(x_1,x_0)f(x_0)dx_0 dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\right|^2 \\
  \le \left[\int_{a}^{x}\cdots\int_{a}^{x_2}\int_{a}^{x_1}|K(x,x_{n-1})\cdots K(x_2,x_1)K(x_1,x_0)||f(x_0)|dx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\right]^{2}
 \\ \le\left(\int_a^x\cdots\int_a^{x_1}|K(x,x_{n-1})\cdots K(x_1,x_0)|^2dx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\right) \\
  \times \left(\int_{a}^{x}\cdots\int_a^{x_1}|f(x_0)|^2dx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\right) \\
 \le \|f\|_{L^2}^2 \int_a^x\cdots\int_{a}^{x_3}\int_a^{x_2}dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_{n-1} \\
 =\|f\|_{L^2}^2\frac{(x-a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
$$
Therefore, after integrating in $x$ on $[a,b]$, one obtains
$$
           \|V_K^n\| \le \sqrt{\frac{(b-a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}} 
$$
That's enough to give an infinite radius of convergence for the exterior resolvent expansion.

Comment: Hi, thank's but i think in the 4-6 line there is a mistake because there is no integral with respect to the variable x.

Comment: @Ann : I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: hi, this part is missing further $ f \left( x \right) =\int_a^x\cdots\int_a^{x_1}|K(x,x_{n-1})\cdots K(x_1,x_0)|^2dx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}$. how we limited it?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives that.

Comment: Sorry, but I understand how we get this with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but how to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to limited this in next line? This is some function of var x

Comment: @Ann : $|\int_{\mbox{Region}}fg|^2 \le \int_{\mbox{Region}}|f|^2 \int_{\mbox{Region}}|g|^2$. Doesn't matter what the region is. For a fixed $x$, you have a region.

Comment: ,sorry, I don't understand where in the next line the function itself disappeared
$ \le\left(\int_a^x\cdots\int_a^{x_1}|K(x,x_{n-1})\cdots K(x_1,x_0)|^2dx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\right) \\
  \times \left(\int_{a}^{x}\cdots\int_a^{x_1}|f(x_0)|^2dx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\right) \\  
 \le g(x)  \|f\|_{L^2}^2 \int_a^x\cdots\int_{a}^{x_3}\int_a^{x_2}dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_{n-1}\\$

Comment: where $ g(x) = \int_a^x\cdots\int_a^{x_1}|K(x,x_{n-1})\cdots K(x_1,x_0)|^2dx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}$